# Measure negative voltages with Fibaro Wall Plug?

Tags: energy, z-wave

I am interested in measuring how much energy my solar cells create. This is a "plug-in" system which connects directly to the socket. My question is whether I can use the Fibaro Wall Plug system to measure *negative* power flows as well?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not related to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked that question to Fibaro support and this is the answers on 12 sept 2016:

---

> Hello, Unfortunately, there is no way to measure a negative power.
>   This functionality was not taken into consideration when the device
>   was designed. I will forward Your suggestion to constructors with
>   question about possibility of integration. If possible, this
>   functionality will be added together with the next firmware versions
>   Ragards

---

I haven't seen an upgrade since.